# TDialogService for numbers only, FMX Delphi

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Is it possible to use **TDialogService** as input dialog with only one OK button? And only showing the numeric keypad (to choose from)?

Comment: Is `TDialogService.InputQuery()` not satisfactory for your needs? Or, are you wanting to remove a Cancel button from it? How do you intend to handle the case where the user wants to cancel input, if you don't provide a Cancel button?

Comment: @RemyLebeau  Hi, I so far I have not used, any simple example? Thanks for help!

Comment: @RemyLebeau I need only OK button is it possible and after click to enter some value show only numeric keyboard.

Comment: "*any simple example?*" - is there something about the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.DialogService.TDialogService.InputQuery) that is unclear to you? Looks like a very straight forward method. "*I need only OK button*" - why? If the standard dialogs don't meet your needs, then just create your own dialog.

Comment: "*after click to enter some value show only numeric keyboard*" - `InputQuery()` is for string input, not numeric input. So no, there is no way to make it display the numeric keyboard. You will have to create your own dialog if you want that.

Comment: This has already been explained in your other question, in the comments you received, which is the exact same comment that @RemyLebeau made above, where it was explained that you need to create your own dialog.